# System V semget creates semaphore but returns 0

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm playing with System V semaphores on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Whenever I make a call to `semget()`, either to create or access an existing semaphore, a value of zero is returned. Per the man pages of `semget`, "If  successful,  the return value will be the semaphore set identifier (a nonnegative integer), otherwise -1 is returned, with errno indicating the error."

I confirm that the sempahore is in fact created by running the `ipcs -s` command.

```
------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner    perms      nsems     
0x00000002 720903     myuser   666        1
```

So in my case, I believe `semget()` should have returned 720903 instead of 0.

Here is my code:

```
static void create_sem(void)

{
int key = 2;
int nsems = 1;
int sem_id;

    printf("Attempting to create new semaphore set with %d members\n", nsems);

    if(sem_id = semget((key_t)key, nsems, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666) == -1) {
        printf("Error creating semaphore\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Successfully created semaphore %d for key %d\n",
        sem_id, key);

    if(semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error destorying semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here's the output

```
Attempting to create new semaphore set with 1 members
Successfully created semaphore 0 for key 2
Error destroying semaphore: Operation not permitted
```

Note, if I hardcode the semid I see by issuing `ipcs -s`, I can successfully remove the semaphore array by using `semctl(720903, 0, IPC_RMID, 0)`.

Why is `semget()` returning 0 instead of the actual semid?

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `=`. You would have found this easily if you had tried to make a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: @EOF, that did it. I was copying an example and forgot the parentheses around the assignment statement. Thanks!